# CSS - 3 Links - Left Align 1, Right Align 2

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have three buttons

```
<div class='button-wrap>
 <a class='button'>First Button</a>
 <a class='button'>Second Button</a>
 <a class='button'>Third Button</a>
</div>
```

What is the best way to left align the first, and right align the second two? Preferably without using float.

I have tried wrapping the second two in a seperate div and using text-align:right but the extra div causes the buttons to go out of alignment with one another.

Comment: "Preferably without using float." Why, what's the issue with using float? Or flexbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with `display:flex` - no need to change your markup

```css
.button-wrap {
  display: flex;
}
.button:nth-child(2) { 
  /* margin left the second button */
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-wrap">
  <a class="button">First Button</a>
  <a class="button">Second Button</a>
  <a class="button">Third Button</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```css
.buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.buttons .button:first-child {
  flex-grow: 1;  
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <div class="button">
    <button>First button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <button>Second button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <button>Third button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox with `justify-content: space-between` on the wrapper, plus put `margin-left: auto` on the second button. This will align everything from there on to the right, while everything before that stys left-aligned.

EDIT: I simplyfied the previous code - less is more efficient...

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

button:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto;  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: lol wow, props to good naming conventions (check my answer) xD

Answer (score 0):

With float, you have to wrap your links into divs like this :

```css
.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class='button-wrap'>
  <div class="left">
    <a class='button'>First Button</a>
  </div>
 <div class="right">
   <a class='button'>Second Button</a>
   <a class='button'>Third Button</a>
 </div>
</div>
```